# On cloning a dropdownlist and it's cascaded dropdownlist,the cascaded dropdownlist is not loading relevant data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have created two asp.net dropdown controls to present a country and it's states.I have one input button here on clicking which, I am supposed to clone the category and it's subcategory dropdownlists(which it does).

Here is the issue:

On changing an index in the countries(Category) dropdown, I am getting the statelist in the subcategory.

But when i clone both the dropdownlists and select a different country in the category, I still get the obsolete values for the previously selected country.
I have shared a screenshot. Here on selecting India as the selected value, I keep getting states of US as the subcategories.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Dropdown" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Category:</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryList" runat="server" class="ddlCountryClass"></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>Sub Category:</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateList" runat="server" class="ddlStateClass"></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="target">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="target2">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>       
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Clones the Category and the subcategory dropdown lists
    $('#btnClone').click(function () {
        $('select.ddlCountryClass:eq(0)').clone();
        var original = $('select.ddlCountryClass:eq(0)');
        var allSelects = $('select.ddlCountryClass');
        clone = original.clone();
        $('#target').append($('<span>').text('Category:'));
        $('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');

        $('select.ddlStateClass:eq(0)').clone();
        var original = $('select.ddlStateClass:eq(0)');
        var allSelects = $('select.ddlStateClass');
        clone = original.clone();
        $('#target2').append($('<span>').text('SubCategory:'));
        $('#target2').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');
    });
    //Fetches subcategory values based on the Category dropdown
    $(function () {
        $('#ddlStateList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#ddlStateList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#ddlStateList').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select State</option>');
        $('#ddlCountryList').change(function () {
            var country = $('#ddlCountryList').val()
            $('#ddlStateList').removeAttr("disabled");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/BindStates",
                data: "{'country':'" + country + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    var options;
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>'
                    }
                    $('#ddlStateList').html(options)
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Something Went Wrong')
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Being rookie in jquery, I have know idea how to achieve the required.
Please share your thoughts!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to `clone(true)`, that way it will copy over the event handlers

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

this passes:

```
clone = original.clone()
```

to this:

```
clone = original.clone(true)
```

Comment: I tried to implement the same but unfortunately that isn't working.it's just the subcategory dropdown that's getting reset to 'Select a state'.